# Unable to build Git Project using Gradle

Tags: gradle, cmd

My project Hydrograph-master cloned from Git is not getting build and throwing error "Gradle is not recognized as internal or external command" while building using command line interface, though I had intalled gradle in my `C:/Gradle` Directory

Comment: Check if Gradle executable is in your PATH: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you're building this project: https://github.com/BitwiseInc/Hydrograph

It has a [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html). It means, that you should not use your local Gradle installation, but a wrapper, bundled in the repo. It is `gradlew.bat` for you (Windows). So, just use `gradlew.bat` instead of `gradle` in CLI:

```sh
gradlew.bat clean
gradlew.bat check
gradlew.bat assemble
```

The wrapper will download required Gradle version for you and use it. This way you'll be using the same Gradle version that project authors meant to be used.

Comment: I have kept my project in eclipse workspace and gradle in C drive. when I ran the graddlewrapper, it downloaded the required gradle version and saved it in C:/Gradle/bin only, but still when I use gradle build command in my project directory through commandline "Gradle is not recognized as internal or external command". Please suggest why my cmd is still not able to able to identify Gradle commands even if the gradle package is installed

Comment: Forget about `gradle` executable. When you are using a wrapper – always use `gradlew.bat`. If you want to use `gradle` – make sure it's in your `PATH` or call it by absolute path: `C:/Gradle/bin/gradle`.

Comment: on using gradlew build and gradlew tasks commands, my Hydrograph-master is build in my maven directory but there are subprojects: hydrograph.engine, hydrograph.server, hydrograph.ui to be built , these didn't got build and they have gradle scripts forbuilding them. How can I build these sbprojects, gradlew hydrograph.engines:tasks throws error "Project 'hydrograph.engine' not found in root project 'Hydrograph-master'"

Comment: Are you not following the installation guide? https://bitwiseinc.github.io/Hydrograph//localInstall